# Best approach to change Xib direction programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, right-to-left

I have an app that has a settings page in which the user can change the app's language. Eventually, the direction of the xibs will change. To explain a bit more, if the language is English for example, the direction will be LTR; However if it's Arabic, it will be RTL.

**Question**

What is the best approach to achieve this?

**Approaches tried with issues**

- **NSUserDefaults :** When setting the language to "ar-SA", the direction changes successfully but **only** when it's called in the main class. When I do it in runtime, the app must be restarted to take effect. Even if there's a way to restart the app, it's not recommended and the app risks to be rejected
- **Multiple xibs :** This approach will work eventually but I have to create **two Xibs** files for each **UIView**. If this is the only solution, can I create two UIViews in one xib file to avoid the confusion?

Any other advice?

Thanks

Comment: how are languages and direction connected?

Comment: If the language is English for example, the direction will be LTR; However if it's Arabic, it will be RTL @Novarg

Comment: You can use a XIB for multiple views, but then according to what you wrote you need to set text fields for one LTR/RTL (opposite of what was set). I guess there should be a more general approach. Just a guess, though.

Comment: If that's the case, I can change the text alignment accordingly programmatically. I just can't seem to find a good, reliable general approach that doesn't require to double the code and the files. @ThomasKilian

Comment: Well, I never had to deal with that (don't speak Arabic, just LTR). But if you loop though the fields in awakeFromNib you should be able to switch either way depending on a setting.

Comment: Yes I guess it can be done. But the issue is that I need the subviews to be mirrored also not just change the direction of the texts in the text fields. @ThomasKilian

Comment: I can imagine. I know what work it is to make a reasonable layout for German/English (due to different text widths for the translations). I consider that a non-trivial problem.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend ditching the in-app language switcher and directing your users to the system-wide language & region prefs where they can set their referred language.

Attempting to hand roll language support in your app will cause an endless amount of issues and bugs for your users, some of which you might not even be able to workaround. Both approaches you provide are already subpar and the second sounds like a maintainability nightmare.

Comment: I completely agree. Since I wasn't the project owner and I didn't convince the concerned otherwise I went for the 2nd approach. 
But surprisingly, some apps like Facebook did a recent update to add the ability to have an in-app language switcher too.

Comment: The maintenance and localization headache you've created with that approach is immense though. I'm not seeing a language picker in the latest Facebook app, but it also still doesn't support split view multitasking, so I'm not sure I would look at them for "best practices".

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that I've only checked Facebook's android version not the iOs one; Seems like they didn't add it there too. But I agree with what you say.