# Localisation and Autolayout

Tags: swift, localization, xcode6, arabic, ios8.1

I am trying to add arabic support in my app , but app has language button , if user selects arabic he can see arabic interface/resources right to left stuff even device language is english . Due to Autolayout I am felling bit issues here

Due to autolayout if i select device language arabic it switches all layouts right to left even app language is english , is there any way I can force to layouts from left to right always

Comment: I doubt this is possible with auto-layout. Remember: this is a company located in California where everything goes LTR and temperature is always around 25 Celsius. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743897/best-approach-to-change-xib-direction-programmatically#comment43899378_27743897

Answer (score 0):

I have been in this situation couple of times. Where we need to switch the layout based on a single language button. Yeah it gets little awkward when we are using AutoLayout. So you can do  one of the following things :

- You can disable the Autolayout & you should flip all the view
  components based on whether user has selected Arabic or English. How
  to do this is for english You need to concentrate on X value of frame
  & then when its arabic start the X of the frame becomes
  **view.frame.width - X**.
- Second thing you can do is as @Kirsteins said you need to change the
  constraints from leading to left & then trailing constraint to right
  constraints. Thats not it you then need to change these constraints
  programatically on the language change.

HTH :)